# Can I have more than one octopus deployment process for a release?

Tags: octopus-deploy

Is it possible to have more than one Deployment Process for a Release?

I have a project named BigDeploy.  It has a deployment process that deploys many things - over 30 projects .  I would like to have another process called TinyDeploy that deploys only one of these projects from the same release already deployed by BigDeploy.

I am a developer and don't have full access to Octopus.  Maybe it's obvious if I could see it.

Comment: I'm not sure I have quite understood your question. But if you need to have two different deployment process, then why not create two different projects in Octopus (that is BigDeploy and TinyDeploy in your case)

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken in the requirements, but [channels](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/channels) could be your answer.
[Paul Stovel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57132/paul-stovell) already answered a similar question [here](https://octopusdeploy.uservoice.com/forums/170787-general/suggestions/5852439-encapsulate-deployment-of-multiple-projects-into-s).

The other alternative could be a `deploy release step` - introduced in `Octopus v 2018.2`. See link to octopus documentation [here](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/projects/coordinating-multiple-projects).